# How do I upload multiple files directly to Amazon S3?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, plupload

I am trying to get the Amazon S3 Plupload [example](https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/blob/master/examples/jquery/s3.php) working with Node.js. However, so far all I have been able to get is `Error #2049`. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have uploaded the crossdomain.xml file.

Here is my policy document and signature:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var s3 = {}
s3.bucket = 'BUCKET';
s3.accessKeyId = 'ACCESS_KEY';
s3.aws_secret_key = 'SECRET_KEY';
s3.policy = JSON.stringify({
    'expiration': '2012-10-01T00:00:00Z',
    'conditions': [ 
      {'bucket': s3.bucket }, 
      {'acl': 'private'},
      ['starts-with', '$key', ''],
      ['starts-with', '$Content-Type', ''],
      ['starts-with', '$name', ''],     
      ['starts-with', '$Filename', ''], 
      {"success_action_status" : "201"}
    ]});
s3.policy = new Buffer(s3.policy).toString('base64');
s3.signature = crypto.createHmac('sha1', s3.aws_secret_key).update(s3.policy).digest('base64');
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'd use a library which can already talk to Amazon S3. I'd recomment AwsSum since I wrote it, but there are others out there.

- https://github.com/appsattic/node-awssum/

Also take a look at the examples so you can see what to do:

- https://github.com/appsattic/node-awssum/tree/master/examples/amazon/s3

Comment: Note: AwsSum is now located here : https://github.com/awssum/ - it now has a plugin architecture, so S3 is located at https://github.com/awssum/awssum-amazon-s3/